# parent and child table foreign key

Tags: postgresql, inheritance, foreign-keys, primary-key

I currently have a parent table:

```
CREATE TABLE members (
    member_id SERIAL NOT NULL, UNIQUE, PRIMARY KEY
    first_name varchar(20)
    last_name varchar(20)
    address address (composite type)
    contact_numbers varchar(11)[3]
    date_joined date
    type varchar(5)
);
```

and two related tables:

```
CREATE TABLE basic_member (
    activities varchar[3]) // can only have 3 max activites
    INHERITS (members)
);

CREATE TABLE full_member ( 
    activities varchar[]) // can 0 to many activities
    INHERITS (members)
);
```

I also have another table:

```
CREATE TABLE planner (
        day varchar(9) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES days(day)
        time varchar(5) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES times(time)
        activity varchar(20) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES activities(activity)
        member bigint FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES members(member_id)
);
ALTER TABLE planner ADD CONSTRAINT pk_planner PRIMARKY KEY (day,time,activity,member);
```

I am currently trying to add with

```
INSERT INTO planner VALUES ('monday','09:00','Weights',2);
```

I have added a set into full_members with

```
INSERT INTO full_members 
VALUES (Default, 'Hayley', 'Sargent', (12,'Forest Road','Mansfield','Nottinghamshire','NG219DX'),'{01623485764,07789485763,01645586754}',20120418,'Full');
```

My insert into Planner is currently not working — can you explain why?

Comment: Same comment as with your other question: please show us the full `CREATE TABLE` and the `INSERT`s you are trying to run.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: What is the error you are getting on the insert into Planner?  Is it a FK reference failure on days, time, or activities -- or indeed of the member number? Is Hayley Sargent member number 2? Separately, are you sure that day and time are best represented with VARCHAR rather than using proper DATE and TIME types?

Answer (score 2):

i managed ot answer my own question it was becuase at the moment posgreSQL doesn't work very well with inheritence and foreign keys, so i have ot create a rule

```
CREATE RULE member_ref
AS ON INSERT TO planner
WHERE new.member NOT IN (SELECT member_id FROM members)
DO INSTEAD NOTHING;
```

this is basically the same as a foreign key

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will be better solution but here it goes...

The principle is quite simple:

- create new table lets call it `table_with_pkeys` which will replicate primary key column(s) of inherited tables `child1`, `child2`, `child3`...
- create triggers on inherited tables, after insert, insert new PK into `table_with_pkeys` newly created PK, after update if it changes update it and after delete delete the same PK from table_with_pkeys.
- Then in every table which should reference child1, child2 or whichever through parent table's PK using FK, point that FK not to parent's PK, but to table_with_pkeys which has copies of all childs PK's, and so you will have easy manageable way to have foreign keys that can cascade updates, restrict updates and so on.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this will have race conditions unless you are using `SERIALIZABLE` transactions for everything, in which case you could just do the checks directly from triggers on the tables from the question, without needing the extra table.

Comment: why would it, any more than the original?  All you are doing is materializing a view of primary keys.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing an open quote before the 12 in the address:

```
INSERT INTO full_members 
VALUES (Default, 'Hayley', 'Sargent', (12 Forest Road', 'Mansfield', 'Nottinghamshire', 'NG219DX'),
        '{01623485764,07789485763,01645586754}',20120418,'Full');
```

should be:

```
INSERT INTO full_members 
VALUES (Default, 'Hayley', 'Sargent', ('12 Forest Road', 'Mansfield', 'Nottinghamshire', 'NG219DX'),
        '{01623485764,07789485763,01645586754}',20120418,'Full');
```

Comment: the insert in to full_members works fine, i can select the record and everything is perfect it is the insert into planner thay i am having problems with

Comment: Ah, well, if you go changing the INSERT as you did, then yes, it will work.

Answer (score 0):

If the materialized view approach doesn't work for you above, create constraint triggers to check the referential integrity.  Unfortunately declarative referential integrity doesn't work well with inheritance at present.